# “Throw out of…” or “throw out from…”?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I wonder which version is correct? Correct me if I am wrong.

> I was thrown out from the place 
>   or 
>   I was thrown out of the place

For example, I am at my friend's house and my friend has a brother and we are hanging out in his room. Then my friend's brother comes and yells: "Get out! Leave!" and throws us out.

Can I say *‘he threw us out from his room’* or *‘he threw us out of his room’*?

Comment: Have you checked any dictionaries? What did you find?

Comment: to remove from a place, office, or employment usually in a sudden or unexpected manner

Comment: It's usually 'throw out of' in the sense of rejecting something undesirable. 'Throw out from' could be used in the sense of 'produce', as in sparks thrown out from a firework, or light thrown out from a lamp.

Comment: Both are grammatical, but they mean different things. Please [edit] your question to describe what your are trying to express.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks! The *of* version sounds more idiomatic there.

Answer (score 1):

Both phrases are correct.

There is a little difference, though.
"Out from" means rather  'out from some object' than 'out from some volume'.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

> ***[out of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of)***
>
> — used as a function word to indicate direction or movement from within to the outside of
>
> // walked out of the room

Merriam-Webster's Dictionary doesn't give examples with 'out from' except some idioms.

Compare two examples from [Reverso.context.net](https://context.reverso.net/traduzione/italiano-inglese/dalle+nostre+case?d=0):

> Is government planning to throw us ***out from*** our homes?
>
> I'm going to throw you ***out of*** this house.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "out of" is used in several meanings.

In the sentence presented, it shows movememt from the inside to the outside of a place.
When you throw something out of a place, you throw it so that it's no longer there.

Some people use the phrase "out from" instead of "out of" in colloquival style, but when it comes to formal English we should use the phrase "out of".

So the use of "out of" is far more idiomatic and common.